# Loop If statements as well run macros after multiple data list selections

Tags: vba, excel

1. I would like the Work Change macro to apply for the entire column.

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address(True, True) = "$P$1" Then
       Select Case Target
       Case "Keep - no action"
           Call KeepNoAction
       Case Else
           Selection.ClearContents
       End Select
   End If
   End Sub
   ```
2. the macro called, "KeepNoAction" I would like it to loop for multiple columns/ rows:

   ```
   Sub KeepNoAction()
   If Range("P1").Value = "Keep - no action" Then
       Range("N1").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range("S1").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S1:AB1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
       Range("S1:AB1").Select
   Else
   End If
   If Range("P2").Value = "Keep - no action" Then
       Range("N2").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range("S2").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:AB2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
       Range("S2:AB2").Select
   End If
   If Range("P3").Value = "Keep - no action" Then
       Range("N3").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range("S3").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S3:AB3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
       Range("S3:AB3").Select
   End If
   ```

Comment: Please don't just tell us `What You would Like`. Please show us `What Have You Tried` and `Where Are you stuck` and `What Error(s) are you getting`

Comment: `If target.column=16 then` will kick in when you change Column P

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing Column P to "Keep - no action", then would you really need to loop instead of just working with the target.row?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Integer
    If Target.Column = 16 Then
        If Target = "Keep - no action" Then
            r = Target.Row

            Cells(r, "S").Value = Cells(r, "N").Value
            Cells(r, "S").AutoFill Destination:=Range("S" & r & ":AB" & r), Type:=xlFillSeries 'Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If

        If Target = "Something else" Then
            MsgBox "Do something else"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Here is a loop you can work with:

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("P1:P" & LstRw)

    For Each c In Rng.Cells

        If c = "Keep - no action" Then
            r = c.Row
            Cells(r, "S").Value = Cells(r, "N").Value
            Cells(r, "S").AutoFill Destination:=Range("S" & r & ":AB" & r), Type:=xlFillSeries    'Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: The code above worked so well!! Thanks so much :) You are a life saver.

Comment: Maybe mark it as the answer, so it doesn't keep popping up as unanswered.